# How to use remote paths in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab

I installed GithubHQ in one server and GitlabCI in another server. But now I need do integration between GitlabHQ and GitlabCI. When I go to add a new project in GitlabCI he requests a path .git project, but the project is on another server where the GitlabHQ.

I tried use the path remote, like: **http://[domain-name]/[user]/[project].git** but he not accept.

I researched about how GitlabCI search the path and found that it does not support remote paths. He use "Rugged::Repository.new(path)" just to get the project on the server.

Does anyone know a way to use paths .git remotes in GitlabCI?

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated by [Issue 36](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/issues/36):

> Actually the purpose of gitlab-ci implies that you install it on deployment point. You install it where you deploy your project

So you are supposed to use a local non-bare repo.

You could, in your case, clone your remote repo on the gitlab-ci server, and use that local path.

> In order to build an integration between gitlab and gitlab-ci:
>
> 1. add gitlab_ci user to git group for read access
> 2. clone your project via git clone /home/git/repositories to somewhere like /home/gitlab_ci/projects/...
> 3. add this project to ci.
> 4. setup gitlabhq to use ci service
>
> Thats all.
>   On `gitlab push` it will trigger gitlab ci to make `git fetch origin`, so testing repo will be always up to date.

Comment: That's it! Thank you!

But two things still do not work as I expected, the status of the last build in GitlabHQ and build automatic so make a push in the project in GitlabHQ.

I do some more configuration for this to work?

Comment: @ElvisMoreira Beside what is described in https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-ci/blob/master/doc/installation.md, I am not sure. I will have to do some more testing.